# Hide menu bar in Firefox 57

Tags: macos, firefox

I'd like to give a presentation in Firefox 57, but I cannot find a way of hiding the menubar/address bar/tab bar when I'm in full screen. I feel like it would be distracting to see that during a slideshow.

Is there a way to hide the menu bar?

I am using Firefox Quantum 57.0b3 (64-bit).

Edit: on OSX.

Comment: solution here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/313241/24974

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F11</kbd> to go fullscreen. This will hide all elements other than the page contents (including all Firefox bars and desktop decorations/bars).

Comment: I edited my question accordingly, but I didn't mention that I am on OSX. For some reason this solution does not work on this platform. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: I can confirm; the tab bar doesnt go away in fullscreen with 1 tab

Answer (score 1):

This is not so easy anymore since the new webextensions add-ons system can no longer modify the UI in that way. Follow below instructions:

Type about:profiles into Firefox. Click the show in finder button next to root directory. This will open your Firefox profile folder.

Create a new folder inside your profile folder called chrome. Create a file called userChrome.css so your path looks like /chrome/userChrome.css

Add this CSS code to your file. Save it. Restart Firefox. Remove the code or comment it out to enable the toolbars again.

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");

#nav-bar { display: none;}

#TabsToolbar {
    visibility: collapse;
}

#main-window[sizemode="maximized"] #titlebar {
    margin-bottom: -34px !important;
}
```

Note: there is a small stripe at the top in fullscreen I couldn't figure out how to fix. If someone figures it out please add to this solution instead of making a new one.

Comment: This is nice, and almost does what I want. It does not hide my bookmarks though. And is there a way to make it only trigger in fullscreen mode?

Comment: I wanted to add that in Firefox 71 beta there is a new command line param --kiosk which can be used to set Firefox in kiosk mode

Answer (score -2):

To go fullscreen in Firefox use the key `F11` or hit the green button on the left hand corner of the window.